# Using JavaScript with Internet Explorer, how do I clear memory without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, memory, memory-management

I have an AJAX-based website using JavaScript on the client.  Certain operations on the site cache large result sets from service calls in the browser (i.e. hundreds of megabytes).  These are throw-away results.  They will be viewed for a short time and then need to be cleared from memory.

I've written a small test site that loads a bunch of junk in memory and then calls JavaScript's `delete` method.  This works great in Firefox (memory almost instantly gets returned).  Internet Explorer 8 (haven't tried 7) doesn't free the memory until the page is refreshed or closed.

Does anyone know how to drop IE's memory usage using JavaScript/Ajax (no page refreshes)?

Below is my sample client code:

```
function load() {
 var x = ['dfjasdlfkjsa;dflkjsad;flkjsadf;lj'];

 for( var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i ) {
  x.push('asdfasfasfsfasdfkasjfslafkjslfjsalfjsaldfkjasl;dfkjsadfl;kjsdflskajflskfjslakfjaslfkjsaldfkjsaldfksdfjk');
 }

 alert('deleting');   // <--- memory usage around 500mb
 delete x;            // <--- immediate results in Firefox 3.5 (not IE8)
 alert('done');
}
```

**UPDATE:** Setting the variable to 'null' does not immediately clear the memory (as that is left up to the garbage collector).  Also, setting a variable null only gets a single reference where there might be multiple references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE (well, technically, JScript) has [an undocumented `CollectGarbage` method](http://ajaxian.com/archives/heap-feng-shui-in-javascript-and-heaplib), which supposedly **forces garbage collector to run immediately**. You might want to play with that, but from my experience, `null`ing references is enough most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the delete method, set the variable to `null`.  This seems to be the best way to clear up memory cross-browser (`delete` is notoriously flaky).  It works the same as my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520680/ie-and-memory-accumulation-in-javascript/520698#520698).

```
alert('deleting');   // <--- memory usage around 500mb
x = null;
alert('done');
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you try "x= null;" instead of delete ?

Comment: But what about the case where I have multiple variables pointing to the same object? Null will just terminate the single reference.

Comment: @j0rdan when you have multiple references to an object, garbage collector will obviously not garbage collect that object until all of the references are seized to exist. `null`'ing all references to an object merely lets GC know that **it is available for garbage collection and can be wiped out next time GC runs**

Answer (score 1):

Just assign null to the variable:

```
x = null;
```

Comment: But what about the case where I have multiple variables pointing to the same object?  Null will just terminate the single reference.

Comment: Yes, you're right, if that's the case, since the delete operator doesn't works quite well on IE, you could nullify all the references you create to the object, that's the price of having a buggy garbage collector... if you can, encourage your users to use a good browser :-)

Answer (score 1):

I realize you mentioned the data is throw away, but, when you delete the nodes, even if just setting x to null, you need to make certain that no event handlers are attached to any of the nodes, otherwise that node cannot be garbage collected.

Here is a function I use in my own code:
http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html