# JavaScript: Iterating over dates

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling

In some application I need to produce an array of dates within specified range. There was a major performance issue with initial approach:

```
var from = new Date("2016-01-01");
var to = new Date("2016-12-31");

for (var current = new Date(from); current <= to; current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary point is that `Date` is a complex object and it's comparison takes significant time. It's better to call `getTime()` to get elementary number value and compare it, as method call overhead is less than time required for comparison operation.

```
for (
  var current = new Date(from);
  current.getTime() <= to.getTime();
  current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1)
);
```

This runs **3x** times faster than initial code! But let's see what else can be done here.

Some general suggestions on performance considerations are made for [Javascript optimizations for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845877/javascript-optimizations-for-internet-explorer) question.

> One common way to optimize performance is caching the 'max' value in for loops.

They say accessing `length` property of array takes some time and should be done once at loop initializer. In our case we call `to.getTime()` at every loop pass. I'm not absolutely sure, but guess it's more time-consuming operation than accessing object attribute.

```
for (
  var current = new Date(from), toTime = to.getTime();
  current.getTime() <= toTime;
  current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1)
);
```

Here's a chart from [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/datesloop):

[image: jsPerf Browserscope Chart]

You can see that caching `to.getTime()` value haven't made any impact for Chrome browser, but looks reasonable for Internet Explorer. I don't know a lot about browser internals, but I think the reason is engine-specific optimizations done automatically.